Is memory barrier NECESSARY for memory consistency?
After reading Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers, I came up with a point which I am not sure of its correctness, as posted in the title.
I came up with this point because of intuition from the CPU cache level (which I am not sure of either): as the MESI protocol and its families guarantee coherence, memory consistency requires memory fences to synchronize across multiple processors, and this requirement would reflect into the programming language internals.
I tried to verify the point with my limited experience:

For C++, fences are directly referred to in its atomic methods, while both of them are applicable for delivering memory consistency;
For Java, Atomic and Lock(AQS) use volatile internally, which employs a memory fence as well.

So, I wonder whether memory fence is necessary to these synchronization issues. In other word, is there any synchronization without any memory fences under the hood?
If the point is too strong, I would wonder whether this point holds in any specific processor, such as x86, ARM, etc.
I really appreciate any advice and keywords.
